# Knockout w/ Bootstrap Modals - Modal appears twice

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js and Bootstrap in my project. I'd like to be able to show a link/button that will open up a modal for that item in my collection. When clicking on the link/button to open my modal for a certain item in the collection, my custom binding's `update` event is fired multiple times, and I'm not sure why this is, nor am I sure how to stop it firing multiple times. How can I accomplish this?

```
    // JavaScript custom binding and model
    ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).modal({
            show: false
        });

        var value = valueAccessor();

        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            $(element).on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
               value(false);
            });
        }

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
           $(element).modal("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).modal('show');
        } else {
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
};

var viewModel = {
  displayModal: ko.observable(false),
  kids: ['Jack', 'Jill']
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

<script type="text/html" id="child-header-template">
<h3 data-bind='text:$data'></h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-bind="click: function () { $root.displayModal(true); }, showModal:  $root.displayModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span>Filler</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>

<div data-bind='foreach: kids'>
<!-- ko template: { name: 'child-header-template' } -->
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

A Jsbin version can be viewed [here](http://jsbin.com/siqusixa/2/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are injecting multiple modals into the page with the same id (#myModal). This is confusing the Bootstrap modal data API (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-data-attrs) and causing it to spawn multiple modals.

Here is a simplified solution (http://jsbin.com/linopelu/2/edit):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$(window.document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = function () {
      var self = this;

      this.displayModal = ko.observable(false);
      this.kids = ['Jack', 'Jill'];
      this.selectedKid = ko.observable();
      this.buttonClick = function () {
        self.selectedKid(this);
      };
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Hello there</h2>
  <!-- ko foreach: kids -->
  <h3 data-bind='text:$data'></h3>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-bind="click: $parent.buttonClick">
  Launch demo modal
  </button>
  <!-- /ko -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div data-bind="with: selectedKid" class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 data-bind="text: $data" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <span>Filler</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution has only one modal that is bound to a selectedKid observable on the view model. When the button is clicked this observable's value is updated and the modal is shown via the bootstrap data API.